# Do AC-increasing items impair a monk's Unarmored Defense as if they were armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, class-feature, monk, armor-class

It's my first campaign, and I'm playing as a monk. My party recently discovered a *ring of protection* that increases AC by 1, and my party members want to give it to me. I didn't know whether wearing it would take away my monk's Unarmored Defense/Unarmored Movement, both of which only work when I'm not wearing armor or carrying a shield.

[Unarmored Defense](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#UnarmoredDefense-226), for instance, says:

> Beginning at 1st level, **while you are wearing no armor** and not wielding a shield, your AC equals 10 + your Dexterity modifier + your Wisdom modifier.

As a monk, would my Unarmored Defense and Unarmored Movement stop working if I was wearing a magical item that increased AC (such as a *ring of protection*), at least by official standing?

Comment: @V2Blast I suspect the question is more about whether magic items that grant AC bonuses in general grant bonuses to unarmored defense.

Comment: @PunksantaTheOriginal Edited to include tags and put the question in the title. How’s it look? You can roll back the edit if it’s not what you wanted to ask.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [What defines an armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132814/what-defines-an-armor); related: [Do Bracers of Defense stack with Mage Armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125442/do-bracers-of-defense-stack-with-mage-armor), [What monk features are disabled whilst wearing armor?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118719/what-monk-features-are-disabled-whilst-wearing-armor)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No, they don't

Items that increase AC are only armor if they specifically state they are. Check the [Armor table](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Armor#content). Everything listed, except for shields, is armor. There are also magical items that are armor, such as [*dragon scale mail*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Items:Dragon%20Scale%20Mail#h-Dragon%20Scale%20Mail). It is armor because it says it is in the description.

A [*ring of protection*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Ring%20of%20Protection?fromList=Ring%20of%20Protection&#content) is a ring and not armor.